# PySide-QtWebKit: CSS font-family has no effect

Tags: python, css, qt, pyside, qtwebkit

In a QWebView, I am dynamically creating and loading HTML using QWebView.setHtml(). In the HTML string that I pass to this method, I have a `<style>` section where I inject a CSS string from an external file. The CSS is working beautifully, except for the font families. The font always falls back to the QWebView default sans-serif font. I can change that default font using `QWebView.settings().setFontFamily(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.StandardFont, "serif")`,  but this simply makes everything on the page a serif font instead of honoring the CSS font-family values.

A relevant section in my CSS file:

```
.page-title {
    color:#BBBBBB;
    font-family:"Times New Roman",Garamond,serif;
}
```

This does not render in a serif font as expected, but in a generic sans-serif font. However, the color displays without issue.

At one point, to debug, I printed the complete HTML string right before calling QWebView.setHtml(), and redirected the output to a file. This file rendered as expected when I opened it in Chromium, leading me to believe that the problem is *not* a HTML/CSS problem. [Here](https://raw.github.com/crayZsaaron/df-legends-reader/master/page.html) is that output if you are interested.

Edit: Since I'm setting a bounty here, here is a quick tl;dr that should sum up everything important:

**With PySide, how can I make a QWebView honor CSS font-family settings in an HTML page that is loaded via QWebView.setHtml()?** Specifically, is there some secret, hidden setting that switches that kind of behavior on and off? Or should I report this as a bug in the framework?

If you want to test this out for yourself, [Here](https://github.com/crayZsaaron/df-legends-reader.git) is a link to the GitHub repo for the project I'm working on. Dependencies are listed in the README.

Comment: Read the computed CSS properties (in the developer tool) and see if there are no rule overwriting your dynamic CSS.

Comment: I seem to be having trouble finding anything in the API that is relevant, besides the method calls that I have already used. However, using JavaScript within the page, I found that the computed style for that section is, in fact, Times! So it's being computed correctly, but something in Qt is overriding it.

Comment: I fairly poor knowledges in the technologies you are using. However, the last thing I can think of at the moment is using `!important` in your CSS rule. Like so: `font-family: "Times New Roman", "Garamond", "serif" !important;`. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks, but no luck there.

Comment: @crayZsaaron I see that the output you are linking to, has Helvetica as font-family. Is that correct, as it is not as you mention in your question?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion, I changed the CSS styles after I made that sample output page and before I asked the question, and also after I asked the question. The point still stands: Part of the page should be rendered in Times New Roman, but is rendered in a sans-serif font. See my answer to Moncho Chavez below.

Comment: As a test, I propose to include the font-family declaration in a style attribute on the element, and see if that works.

Answer (score 4):

In the header of Page.html (the one you linked) https://raw.github.com/crayZsaaron/df-legends-reader/master/page.html

I found this..

```
.page-title {
    color:#BBBBBB;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Maybe try to delete this, or replace it with this

```
.page-title {
    color:#BBBBBB;
    font-family:"Times New Roman",Garamond,serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I've switched around the CSS a bunch before and since asking the question. The styles I gave in my question may not necessarily match up with the styles in the project currently. Right now, I think the header is supposed to be in Helvetica, but the page content is supposed to be in Times New Roman, and the HTML is computed as such on page load, but then overriden somehow by Qt. Sorry for the confusion there.

Comment: I will need to see the error on a running to inspect the element and see wich css is afecting it, you can do it.. Rigth click on chrome, "inspect element".

Comment: In Chrome, that HTML file displays properly, so there is no "problem element" to inspect. The problem is not with the HTML/CSS, it is with Qt.